# proof by induction: off by a factor of 3

Tags: induction

I put something into wolfram alpha and I saw that it simplified really well. I wanted to try and prove it, but my attempt is leaving me short a 3. Where am I going wrong?

$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 3^{m-1-i}2^{i} = 3^m - 2^m$

Base case: m = 1

$\sum_{i=0}^{0} 3^{1-1-0}2^{0} = 1$

$3^m - 2^m = 3^1 - 2^1 = 1$

Then we have our ind. hyp.

$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 3^{k-1-i}2^{i} = 3^k - 2^k$

Now to prove for k + 1

$\sum_{i=0}^{k} 3^{k-i}2^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 3^{k-1-i}2^{i} + 3^02^k = 3^k - 2^k + 2^k = 3^k + 2^{k+1}$

Which does not prove our hypothesis. Can someone help?

Comment: Usually, the best thing to do in this situation is to fix $k$ and go through it line by line.  You know the claim is true for $k=1$, right (you seem to switch between $m,k$ so I'm not sure).  Now, try for $k=2$.  Go though your computation to see where your error occirs.

Comment: $-2^k+2^k = 0\neq 2^{k+1}$

Comment: Though, really, isn't it easier to just pull out the multiplicative factor of $3^{m-1}$ and then use the closed form for the geometric sum of $\sum \left(\frac 23\right)^i$?

Comment: When you went from $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k3^{\color{red}{k-i}}2^i$ to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(\cdots)+(\text{last term})$, the summands should not have changed appearance.  You somehow replaced the exponent in the $3$ there.  It should have been $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}3^{\color{red}{k-i}}2^i + 3^02^k$ which you can factor a $3$ out of.  The very final punchline needed should be that $2=3-1$

Comment: $3^0 - 2^0 \ne 1$

Comment: Thank you  Lulu and Jmoravitz. I tried using k+1 and checking values and I got 3=5. Then I checked the summands and corrected them. $\sum_{i=0}^{k} 3^{k-i}2^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 3^{k-1}2^{i} + 3^02^k =3\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 3^{k-1-i}2^{i} + 3^02^k= 3(3^k - 2^k) + 2^k = 3^{k+1} - 3*2^{k}+2^k =  3^{k+1} - 2^{k+1}$

Comment: If you are interested, an extension of this problem is $\sum 2^{a}3^{b}4^{c}=\frac{1}{2}\left[4^{m}-2\cdot 3^{m}+2^{m}\right]$ where the summation is over all possible integer solutions of $a+b+c=m-2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer, you have the summand $3^{m-i}2^{i}$ on the LHS but $3^{m-1-i}2^{i}$ on the RHS.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{m}3^{m-i}\cdot 2^{i}
&=
3\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}3^{m-1-i}\cdot 2^{i} + 2^{m}
\\
&=3\cdot\left(3^{m}-2^{m}\right) + 2^{m}
\\
&=
3^{m+1}-2^{m+1}
\end{aligned}
$$