# Evaluate Sum of Products in The Form of $\sum_{\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|=C}\prod_{i=0}^{n}\left(2+i\right)^{x_{i}}$

Tags: solution-verification, summation, combinatorial-proofs

**Background**

I recently came across the problem to prove the following:

$$
\sum_{\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|_{1}=m-1}2^{x_{1}}3^{x_{2}}
=
3^{m}-2^{m},
\phantom{x}
\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^{2}
$$

A proof by induction is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835308/751970). A combinatorial proof is also quite straightforward:

We have $m$ customers standing in a queue to visit one of three stalls.

*LHS*

The summand $2^{x_{1}}3^{x_{2}}$ is the number of possibillities where customer number $x_{1}+1$ is the first to visit the third stall. Therefore, the LHS is the total number of possibilities where at least one customer visit the third stall.

*RHS*

The RHS is simpler. Out of $3^{m}$ possibilities, we subtract those in which the third stall receives no customer: $2^{m}$.

**Problem Statement**

I wish to extend the problem and evaluate the following expression:

$$
\sum_{\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|_{1}=m-n}\prod_{i=0}^{n}\left(2+i\right)^{x_{i}}
=
\phantom{x}
?
\phantom{x},
\phantom{x}
\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^{n+1}
$$

**My Attempt**

Using a similar approach to the original problem, I was able to prove that

$$
\sum_{\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|_{1}=m-2}2^{x_{1}}3^{x_{2}}4^{x_{3}}
=
\frac{1}{2}\left[
4^{m}-2\cdot 3^{m}+2^{m}
\right],
\phantom{x}
\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^{3}
$$

Again we have $m$ customers standing in a queue, this time to visit one of four stalls.

*LHS*

The summand $2^{x_{1}}3^{x_{2}}4^{x_{3}}$ is the number of possibilities where customer number $x_{1}+1$ is the first to visit the third stall and customer number $x_{1}+x_{2}+2$ is the first to visit the fourth stall. The LHS is then the total number of possibilities where the third and fourth stalls have customer(s) and the third stall receives a customer before the fourth stall.

*RHS*

There are $4^{m}$ total possibilities. Of these:

- $3^{m}-2^{m}$ possibilities that third stall receive customer(s) but the fourth stall does not
- $3^{m}-2^{m}$ possibilities that fourth stall receive customer(s) but the third stall does not
- $2^{m}$ possibilities that neither the third nor the fourth stall receive any customer

Therefore, there are $4^{m}-2\cdot\left(3^{m}-2^{m}\right)-2^{m}=4^{m}-2\cdot 3^{m}+2^{m}$ possibilities where both the third and fourth stalls receive customer(s). In half of these possibilities, the third stall receives a customer before the fourth stall does.

**Remaining Challenge**

Using this approach, I can prove the problem for an arbitrary $n$. However, it quickly becomes too tedious. I am wondering if anyone knows a more straightforward alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have from first principles that we seek

$$[z^{m-n}] \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{1-(2+q)z}
= [z^{m-n}] (1-z) \prod_{q=1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{1-qz}
\\ = [z^{m-n}] \prod_{q=1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{1-qz}
- [z^{m-n-1}] \prod_{q=1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{1-qz}
\\ = [z^{m+2}] \prod_{q=1}^{n+2} \frac{z}{1-qz}
- [z^{m+1}] \prod_{q=1}^{n+2} \frac{z}{1-qz}
= {m+2\brace n+2} - {m+1\brace n+2}.$$

We have for the first term

$$\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{n+2} (-1)^{n+2-j} {n+2\choose j} j^{m+2}$$

and the second

$$\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{n+2} (-1)^{n+2-j} {n+2\choose j} j^{m+1}$$

Collect both to get

$$\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{n+2} (-1)^{n+2-j} {n+2\choose j} (j-1) j^{m+1}
\\ = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+2} (-1)^{n+2-j} {n+1\choose j-1} (j-1) j^m.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n!}
\sum_{j=2}^{n+2} (-1)^{n-j} {n\choose j-2} j^m.}$$

For example with $n=2$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2}
\left[ (-1)^{2-2} {2\choose 2-2} 2^m
+ (-1)^{2-3} {2\choose 3-2} 3^m
+ (-1)^{2-4} {2\choose 4-2} 4^m \right]
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [ 2^m - 2 \times 3^m + 4^m]$$

matching the result by OP.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$, and let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be distinct. Then consider the generating function

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} z^m \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{n} \\ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{1}=m}}\prod_{i=1}^{n} r_i^{x_{i}}.
\end{align*}

Rearranging, we get

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{n}}\prod_{i=1}^{n} (r_i z)^{x_{i}}
= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1 - r_i z} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{r_k^{n-1}}{\prod_{i \in [n] \setminus\{k\}} (r_k - r_i)} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - r_k z} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{r_k^{m+n-1}}{\prod_{i \in [n] \setminus\{k\}} (r_k - r_i)} \biggr) z^m.
\end{align*}

In the second step, we utilized partial fraction decomposition. Hence it follows that

$$ \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{n} \\ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{1}=m}}\prod_{i=1}^{n} r_i^{x_{i}}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{r_k^{m+n-1}}{\prod_{i \in [n] \setminus\{k\}} (r_k - r_i)}, $$

or equivalently,

$$ \bbox[color:navy; padding:8px; border:1px navy dotted; background:#feffed;]{\sum_{\substack{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{n} \\ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{1}=m-n+1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n} r_i^{x_{i}}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{r_k^m}{\prod_{i \in [n] \setminus\{k\}} (r_k - r_i)}.} $$

> **Example 1.** If $n = 2$, $r_1 = 2$ and $r_2 = 3$, then
>
> $$ \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{2} \\ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{1}=m-1}} 2^{x_1}3^{x_2}
> = \frac{2^m}{2-3} + \frac{3^m}{3-2}
> = 3^m - 2^m. $$

> **Example 2.** If $n = 3$, $r_1 = 2$, $r_2 = 3$, and $r_3 = 4$, then
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}_0^{3} \\ \|\mathbf{x}\|_{1}=m-2}} 2^{x_1}3^{x_2}4^{x_3}
> &= \frac{2^m}{(2-3)(2-4)} + \frac{3^m}{(3-2)(3-4)} + \frac{4^m}{(4-2)(4-3)} \\
> &= \frac{1}{2}[4^m - 2 \cdot 3^m + 2^m].
> \end{align*}